# Is there a way to append "suffix" to javascript function through a select?

Tags: javascript, function, select

I don't know exactly what this is called or if its even possible. But basically I want to add stuff to an "incomplete" method. For example.

```
captureDog =()=>{
  alert('caught dog');
}

captureCat =()=>{
  alert('caught cat');
}

<select id="pet">
   <option value="Cat">cat</option>
   <option value="Dog">dog</option>
</select>
```

Essentially I have a whole bunch of capture methods (I will either hard-code write them myself or create another method that creates them). I want to essentially call a different method depending on what value is on the select (behaves as suffix of method). Some dummy code I have that is trying to do what I'm saying is below.

```
var selectField = document.getElementById("pet");
selectField.addEventListener("onchange", "capture"+ selectField.value ="()");
```

Preferably I would like this to be done with just plain javascript.

EDIT: Grammar
EDIT2: Fixed arrow Functions

Comment: Assuming global scope, `window['capture'+selectField.value]()` would do it, if you fixed the uppercase-lettering issue. Otherwise, build a map eg. `({cat: captureCat, dog: captureDog})[selectField.value]();`

Comment: Looks like your first snippet has syntax errors. You mean to do `function captureDog() {`. You're confusing function declarations with arrow functions.

Comment: Thanks for notticing the capitalizing error. I have a question for both of your suggestions... How do they work? To clarify, I never used anything with windows[] before and also the map thing... how does that work?

Comment: `function capture(type) { alert("caught " + type); }` if something like this doesn't work, please provide an example that represents your actual problem better and why this solution does not work.

Comment: @Shelyb115 Thanks for the response. I don't think your method would work as capturecat() and capturedog() do entirely two different things. I just have alert statements right now to test if it correctly calls the correct methods.

Comment: An easy way to do this would be to use an Object that contains key value pairs where the value is the function you want to run and the key is the name of the function.

Comment: That seems brittle. What if an option was selected for which there was no capture function? Or if the select field was cleared out? There's no function to be called in those cases and you'd get an error. Why don't you create a function that makes a call to the function you need based on the select field value? `selectField.addEventListener("onchange", handleNewSelectValue);`

Answer (score 2):

I think something like this:

```
var selectField = document.getElementById("pet");

let X = {
    cat: function(){
    console.log("cat 123")
  },
    dog: function(){
    console.log("dog 123")
  }
}

selectField.addEventListener("change", x => {
let val = x.target.options[x.target.selectedIndex].value

X[val]();

});
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5rnke6zy/10/